# How to find child element while having found the parent div?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webautomation

I have a google form that I am webscraping(at least trying to). I want to look through it to find text where it says "Name ", then find the parent div of the whole block that contains that question and look for an input element where I can use send_keys() to fill out my name. I was able to find "Name " and find the parent div.

```
src = result.content
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://exampleform.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find(string="Name ")
nameBlock = name.find_parents('div', class_="freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer", limit = 1)

if soup.find(string="Name "):
  print('yes')
#prints yes

if name.find_parents('div', class_="freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer", limit = 1):
  print('okay')

#prints okay

if nameBlock.find('input'):
  print('yup')  

#gets error

# Also have tried nameBlock.find(tag = 'input')
# and nameBlock.find_element_by_tag_name('input)
# and name.find_parents('div', class_="freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer", limit = 1).find('input)
```

I have tested out that I have found the parent function by printing out the variable "nameBlock" and was able to get the whole parent div and saw with the input tag there in the console. But then I get this error when I try the use the final "if" statement to see if I was able to locate the input element:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I think it has the parent selected as each child within that parent as well so every child is looking for

```
nameBlock.find('input')
```

but I am not really sure how I would go about just selecting the child input element. Any suggestions? Also here is the HTML to better help understand my issue.

[image: Screenshot of HTML]

Comment: can you add part of the html code you are trying to parse with BS

Comment: is this html code dynamicaly created by javascript or it exists staticaly? BS will fetch the static html code, cannot run javascript to generate the rest page

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

The error says that You have used `find_elements_by_tag_name()` which returns as `list` not the `webelement`.

Change this to

`find_element_by_tag_name()` which will return as webelement and you can now use `send_keys()` method.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and got the same error of AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag_name'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? except it says element instead of element but your suggestion made logical sense yet unfortunately did not  work

Comment: @DanielOcampo : Share your url if possible?

Comment: The url you are working and wanted to provide data in input field?

Comment: How would I go about doing that again?